# Python: Can you name an object with a value stored in a variable?

Tags: python, object, variables, python-turtle

### Hi, I'm F2C

---

It is easy to write a program in python that makes 1, 2, 3 objects.

But how do you make 100, 200, 300 objects, all with different names?

I tried to use a counting variable to get the name, e.g. object1, object2, object3,...

**But when I try to use that variable's value as a name, I just get an object with a name of the variable, NOT it's value.**

---

So the question is:

#### How to name an object with a value of variable?

---

Here is an example:
I want to make 100 python turtles with names T1, T2, T3,...,T99, T100 using a simple loop.

```
import turtle
n = "T"
for i in range(1, 100):
    n = "T" + str(i) 
    n = turtle.Turtle() # Here is the problem
```

Instead, **I only get 1 turtle named "n".** I also tried with string formatting, but it also didn't go well.

---

*I know this this question might seem unnecessary, but I am just curious if it is possible or is there some better solution.*

Comment: You could generate a list of objects where each object can be accessed with the index to the list. So there is no need for a "variable-name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create list of Objects eg:

```py
n = []
for i in range(1,100):
    n.append(turtle.Turtle())
```

Read more about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-list-of-object-in-python-class/

Comment: List is the way to go here. Unless you *really* want to name objects, in which case you can use a `dict`. Could you please fix `appned` -> `append` since it is too short to submit as an edit.

Comment: Thank you a lot @HARSHMITTAL. But how do I retrieve the object from list? For example, if I want 50th turtle to go forward or something like that?

Comment: n[49].forward(50)